# how can I extract the google sheets ID from the URL using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

I see lots of regular expression solutions in other languages, but I know R.

Example URL provided from Google Sheet share button:

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/crazyLongIDstring/edit

I want to algorithmically extract crazyLongIDstring using the particular regular expression implementation in R, which is slightly different from other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use base R extracting approach, you may use a cleaner regex with it:

```
getSheetID<-function(URL){
  regmatches(URL, regexpr("/spreadsheets/d/\\K[^/]+", URL, perl=TRUE))[1]
}

x <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/crazyLongIDstring/edit"
getSheetID(x)
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/hmuHJa) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j2zL0B/1). The `regexpr` function will fetch you the first match found if any. If there is no match, you will end up with an NA rather than the input string.

**Regex details**

- `/spreadsheets/d/` - a literal string
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the various R regex, grep, gsub, etc. functions challenging to implement. I know there's a simpler syntax in stringr, but here's the solution with sub()

```
x<-"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/crazyLongIDstring/edit"
gSheetID=sub(pattern="^.*/spreadsheets/d/(.*)/.*$",replacement="\\1",x=x)
gSheetID
```

* The \1 replacement returns the capture group (.*) with the ID string of interest

I wanted this as a function, so here it is, in case it's useful:

```
getSheetID<-function(URL){
  sub(pattern="^.*/spreadsheets/d/(.*)/.*$",replacement="\\1",x=URL)}
getSheetID(x)
```